# PHP simple fruitmachine stuck with random integer/string

Tags: php, string, random

So i'm trying to make a fruitmachine.
Basically a function that gives a random string of A, B or C (3 times like A-B-C or B-C-C).
When the letters are 3 times the same (A-A-A for instance) It should Echo the text Jackpot.

(After i got this working i wanted to show the random strings that i created and give each row a different color)

Now i got the part working where i have 3 inputs that give a random number (somehow i can't get strings to work). And then it checks if the 3 numbers are the same or not. If not it says you lost, if it's the same it says you won!.

But i can't get the numbers that i randomly created to show. + it should be strings not integers (so it should create A,B,C at random for each of the inputs and it should also echo them/show them)

Hopefully my explenation is a bit clear :) anyway : here is the code that i've made thus far
I've been fiddling with the integers that should be strings and how to show them mainly..

```
function fruitmachine()
{
    $input1 = rand(0,2);
    $input2 = rand(0,2);
    $input3 = rand(0,2);
        if($input1 == $input2 && $input2 == $input3)
        {
            echo "Jackpot";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "You lost";
        }
}
echo fruitmachine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a range of letters thru `range()` and get a random value from them with `array_rand()`, after that, store their values and compare:

```
function fruitmachine()
{
    $input1 = range('A', 'C'); // create an array('A', 'B', 'C')
    $input2 = range('A', 'C');
    $input3 = range('A', 'C');

    $results1 = $input1[array_rand($input1)]; // randomize 'A', 'B', 'C'
    $results2 = $input2[array_rand($input2)];
    $results3 = $input3[array_rand($input3)];
    echo $results1, '<br/>', $results2, '<br/>', $results3, '<br/>';
    return ($results1 == $results2 && $results2 == $results3) ? 'Jackpot' : 'You lost';
}
echo fruitmachine();
```

Comment: Okay thanks! i'll give that a try. What does the return function do/mean exactly? (the ? 'Jackpot' : 'You lost'; part). Is it just a shorter way to make an if/else or?

Edit: I notice that with this i get 3x a random ABC
The idea behind it is that i get 1 row of ABC. So input1 creates either A, B or C, input2 the same etc. So from those 3 inputs i get a string that could be A-C-A until it hits for instance A-A-A and then you have jackpot.

Comment: @Xereoth sure man, actually thats a simple ternary operator (shorthand if), if inside the condition satisfy then return ` ? jackpot`, else `: you lost`

Comment: @Xereoth could you rephrase the test case, i don't quite understand what you mean by that

Comment: Okay Now it echo's 3 lines with ABC so example:
ACA
BCA
CDA
You Lost.

While i would like to have just 1.
I think i overcomplicate myself with the 3 inputs. I assume in this case i can just use 1 input? :P (but i thought i needed to have 3 inputs that all 3 create 1 letter and those 3 combined should make a combination of A-A-A (where each letter is a different input, because i figured that would be the easiest way to check if you got jackpot or you lost, by comparing the 3 inputs and if their equal you won)

Comment: @Xereoth okay i get it now, il revise it

Comment: I used this now:
    $input1 = str_shuffle('ABC');
    echo $input1, '<br/>';
    return ($input1 == "AAA" || $input1 == "BBB" || $input1 == "CCC") ? 'Jackpot' : 'You lost';

I guess this works with what i meant no? Edit: I see that now i never get the same letters it's always 3 different ones, therefor i can never get jackpot.

Comment: Okay ^_^, got a lot to learn still i see...

Let me try the revision =) thanks for you help, really appreciate it!

Comment: It seems to work. But somehow the return function doesn't work. When it's A-A-A as output it still says i lost but when its B-A-B it says you won. Which is strange since it compares 1 + 2 and then 2 + 3

Comment: @Xereoth yes i noticed, that wrong assignment il change it for a moment

Comment: @Xereoth dumb mistake, anyway check my revision, that should crack it

Comment: Okay, but how come that this works (to me it looks the same code but you just put the array_rand in a different variable?)
But indeed this works great! Really appreciate your time and help! Now i can start cracking on the CSS etc. to make it look like a slot machine ^_^

Comment: @Xereoth no, it was a dump mistake, the function `array_rand()` is reapeated all over the place, and therefore each use of it yields another result, i forgot to store them, then compare

Comment: To avoid uncertainty in results, i would use " The php identical operator instead of the comparison one.     return ($results1 === $results2 && $results2 === $results3)?'':'';

Comment: @Mubo well you could, but in this case, 3 arrays are just explicitly made up of strings inside, so i don't think being strict here is not really needed.